# How Should Transactions within a large Stored Procedure be handled?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions

In one of several stored procedures I work with.. things are structured this way:

```
[begin stored proc]
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

[dump data to # tables, lots and lots of manipulation]
[output to display layer]

[UPDATES and INSERTS]
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   [handle errors]
END CATCH
[end stored proc]
```

This "template" of rolling back transactions and handling errors was essentially handed to me by someone else on the team, answering the boss's decree that data modification should not occur in case of any failure in the SP. Now I'm trying to better understand transactions, how to implement them, best practices, etc. This looks like it flies in the face of a lot of the basics I'm reading.

I'm thinking it should look like this:

```
[begin stored proc]
BEGIN TRY

[dump data to # tables, lots and lots of manipulation]
[output to display layer]

BEGIN TRANSACTION
[UPDATES and INSERTS]
COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   [handle errors]
END CATCH
[end stored proc]
```

That would work fine for this stored proc, my question is what if we have an SP that is structured like this:

```
[begin stored proc]
BEGIN TRY

[dump data to # tables, lots and lots of manipulation]
[output to display layer]

BEGIN TRANSACTION @one
[UPDATES and INSERTS]
COMMIT TRANSACTION @one

[more manipulation based on results of tran @one]

BEGIN TRANSACTION @two
[UPDATES and INSERTS]
COMMIT TRANSACTION @two

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [@one? @two?]
   [handle errors]
END CATCH
[end stored proc]
```

After @one is committed, there's no rolling it back if any subsequent commands fail, right? I admit I can't imagine a scenario where all the DML couldn't be placed at the end in a single transaction, but then again I'm not that imaginative. In a situation were, in the case of any failure ALL DML must be rolled back, is the only solution to group it all at the end, or wrap the whole thing in a transaction?

(I could be fundamentally misunderstanding something here, if so sorry for the dumb questions)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as transaction name. As there are no nested transactions in MSSQL - regardless of `@@trancount` value, calling `rollback tran` will reduce it to zero. And if transaction has been fully committed, there is no way back (save for point-in-time database restore).

Best practice while dealing with transactions is to keep them as short as possible. At least on OLTP systems (or why you would ever need them otherwise?). I don't know how much data is affected by your sp's logic, but the task looks suspiciously similar to ETL, which normally happens to live a happy life without any transactions, because it's usually re-playable by its nature.

If that's not the case, make sure your database has plently of room for its transaction log to grow, because rollback puts twice as much data into it as commit would at the same point. Oh yes, and it also takes time and disk resources, and holds all locks until the rollback is completed. The same is true for version storage in `tempdb` database, if any of versioning modes has been enabled in your main db.

If you haven't figured it out already, I mean that either your task is ETL-like and the boss is wrong about transactions, or it is actually possible to split these changes into smaller, more manageable units of work. Because if the transaction footprint is 1 Gb or more, rolling it back may take so long that someone with short temper will decide to kill the spid, or restart the service, thus only increasing the amount of headache.

Comment: It's not necessarily ETL like, I don't think. Use case here (and for several other SPs like this one) is to generate Invoices for accounts (that's the display layer). The DML at the end is to mark each invoice as having been sent, an UPDATE and an INSERT. That DML cannot happen if there's any failure in the SP at all, for legal reasons, but it is a relatively small portion of the sp. None of the manipulation of data for display actually commits anything to the DB.

Comment: Also: can you explain this: "There is no such thing as transaction name. As there are no nested transactions in MSSQL - regardless of @@trancount value, calling rollback tran will reduce it to zero. And if transaction has been fully committed, there is no way back (save for point-in-time database restore)." - it seems to contradict what I'm seeing here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx

Comment: @MasonFrazee, you can create a named transaction, yes, but you cannot rollback a transaction by its name - all currently opened transactions in this session (that is, "nested") will be rolled back. The only case when you do have a meaningful name is a transaction savepoint - you can roll back to it. But this is an entirely different story, and savepoints will not help you in this particular case.

Comment: Well, you can implement a queue for sending invoices (you probably mean sending e-mails, or Service Broker messages?). This will provide guaranteed delivery (i.e. atomicity) without overextending the database transaction. Besides, are you sure that all invoices must be processed in the same transaction? They are usually independent entities, each for itself...

Comment: Well, we error check and spit out "bad" invoices to a report, but this is to handle unknowns or unforeseen errors. Essentially, if any unexpected error happens, the entire batch must be held up (meaning the last part that marks them as send can not happen). But I think the main question remains... no point in putting all the code that does NOT affect data in the transaction?

Comment: @MasonFrazee, yes, unless you work under a highly isolated TIL with a lot of parallel processing that can change the data from outside of the current session, there is no need to put `select`s into the transaction. This will reduce the amount of locks and jogs up things a bit, in general.